# how can I add new post on top of firebaseAnimatedList.? help me out, whenever i add new post its going at the bottom of of the post

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-animatedlist

I want when someone add new post it should appear on the top of the post.

I also used reverse from listview but it wont worked.

```
await Future.value(uploadTask);
   var newUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();

   final User? user = _auth.currentUser;

        postRef.child('Post List').child(date.toString()).set({

          'pId': date.toString(),
          'pImage': newUrl.toString(),
          'pTime': date.toString(),
          'pTitle': titleController.text.toString(),
          'pDescription': descriptionController.text.toString(),
          'uEmail': user!.email.toString(),
          'uid': user.uid.toString(),

     }).then((value){
        toastMessage('Post Published');
        setState(() {
          showSpinner = false;
        });
    } ).onError((error, stackTrace) {
         toastMessage(error.toString());
         setState(() {
           showSpinner = false;
         });
   });

}catch (e) {
   setState(() {
   showSpinner = false;
    });
```

...

```
Expanded(child: FirebaseAnimatedList(

    query: dbRef.child('Post List'),
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot, Animation<double> animation, int index) {

  return  Container(

      child: Column(

            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
                    FadeInImage.assetNetwork(image: snapshot.value['pImage'], placeholder: 'assets/x.png',),
              SizedBox(height: 5.0),

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Text(snapshot.value['pTitle'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Text(snapshot.value['pDescription'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal), ),
              ),

              SizedBox(height: 20),
      ],
          ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"reverse: true" add to firebaseanimatedlist